# What are the technical terms of these fiddle sounds?

Tags: terminology, violin

I am curious to know what these 3 sounds, produced by a fiddle, are called:

[Sound 1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=10FRNLhntoW7yzolKVIFmOLYnxBVRi6oz)

[Sound 2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1M4k9JlId3tYt2LG_d0IE56riNoYy9fcf)

[Sound 3](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aw5mSnDuxvsPO02LS3izBdT2nUejtTyd)

Comment: In non-technical terms, how is sound 2 being produced?

Comment: I can't play them :(

Comment: When you click on a link, in upper right corner there is an arrow pointing down, when you click on that it gets downloaded, its just a wav file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Ricochet or Flying Spiccato bowing with a harmonic note at the end.
2. Tapping / Knocking on the wood of the violin, probably with a knuckle from the bow hand.
3. Heavy Staccato or Marcato, stopping the bow on the string.

Comment: Some of these, and other non-classical effects are demonstrated here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NprC8ZorM0A